# Autofac - memory leak

Tags: c#, entity-framework, memory-leaks, singleton, autofac

I've created simple factory to creating Entity Framework's DbContext. It's implemented like this (simplified code):

```
public class ContextFactory : IContextFactory
{
    private Func<IDbContext> _dbContext;

    public ContextFactory(Func<IDbContext> dbContext)
    {
        _dbContext = dbContext;
    }

    public IDbContext CreateContext()
    {
        var context = _dbContext();
        context.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;

        return context;
    }
}
```

As you see DbContext is injected to my factory as Func and created every time when CreateContext() is called.

Registration in bootstrapper is:

```
builder
            .RegisterType<ContextFactory>()
            .As<IContextFactory>()
            .SingleInstance();
```

So factory is singleton and context registration:

```
builder
            .RegisterType<OdynDbContext>()
            .AsImplementedInterfaces()
            .InstancePerDependency();
```

is instance per dependency.

I use created context in using() block so it should be disposed every time:

```
public TestClass
{
    private readonly IContextFactory _contextFactory;
    public TestClass(IContextFactory contextFactory)
    {
        _contextFactory = contextFactory;
    }

    public void TestMethod()
    {
       using(var context = _contextFactory.CreateContext())
       {
           ... operations on context
       }
    }
```

And unfortunately context isn't disposed correctly. It stays somewhere in memory and causes leak. I don't know why. I overrided Dispose() method in DbContext and it is called. Anyone has met with such a problem?

Comment: Does `OdynDbContext` implement `IDisposable`?

Comment: Are you sure that is DBContext causing memory leaks? It could be the connection to the database and it could be related to connection pooling.

Comment: "It stays somewhere in memory and causes leak." -- how do you know it's staying in memory somewhere?

Comment: I think you are having a [Captive Dependency](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/06/02/captive-dependency/). Try making the `ContextFactory` registration (and all its parents) either scoped or InstancePerDependency instead.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to use .ExternallyOwned() extension method while registering DbContext:

```
builder
   .RegisterType<DbContext>()
   .AsImplementedInterfaces()
   .ExternallyOwned()
```

Then wrapping it in `using` block causes proper disposal of object.